# Align nav-items to right side in bootstrap-4

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

I just switched to bootstrap 4 and reworking all my html and scss to work with it and I cant seem to find how to put a group of nav-items on the right side of the navbar. This is my navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
        <%= link_to "Living Recipe", recipes_path(sort_attribut: "popularity", sort_order: :desc), class: "navbar-brand" %>
        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="navbarResponsive">   
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-md-left">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <%= form_tag(recipes_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form", class: "form-inline") do %>
                            <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Recipes", class: "form-control col-md-8" %>
                    <% end %>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="responsiveNavbarDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Browse</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="responsiveNavbarDropdown">
                        <%= link_to "Popular", recipes_path(sort_attribute: "popularity", sort_order: :desc), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                        <%= link_to "Newest", recipes_path(sort_attribute: "created_at", sort_order: :desc), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                        <%= link_to "Most Updated", recipes_path(sort_attribute: "most_active", sort_order: :desc), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                        <%= link_to "Most Saved", recipes_path(sort_attribute: "save_count", sort_order: :desc), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-md-right">
                <% if user_signed_in? %>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <%= current_user.displayname.present? ? "D-ring" : current_user.firstname %>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="responsiveNavbarDropdown">
                            <%= link_to "Profile", user_path(current_user.id), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                            <%= link_to "Recipe Box", user_saved_recipes_path(current_user.id), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                            <%= link_to "Add Recipe", new_recipe_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
                            <%= link_to "Submitted Recipes", user_path(current_user.id), class: "dropdown-item" %>
                            <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, class: "dropdown-item" %>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <% else %>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <%= link_to "Create Account", '', data: {:'toggle' => 'modal', :'target' => '#signupModal'}, class: "nav-link" %>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <%= link_to "Login", '', data: {:'toggle' => 'modal', :'target' => '#loginModal'}, class: "nav-link" %>
                    </li>           
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

And this is the screenshot of what it looks like

[image]

Comment: Latest solution based on alpha 6 http://stackoverflow.com/a/41513784/171456

Comment: According to the [bootstrap 4 alpha 6 documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/), you can use `ml-auto` on the `<ul>` element you want to float right in the navbar.

Comment: for ul with class 'navbar-nav' and add 'w-100' as well, and with first link on left add class 'mr-auto' this for make sure incase you have Collapsed navbar, not need CSS sure if you use bootstrap or media query , first look for their classes

Answer (score 440, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

Create another `<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">` for the navbar items you want on the right.
`ml-auto` will pull your `navbar-nav` to the right where `mr-auto` will pull it to the left.

### Tested against Bootstrap v4.5.2

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <style>
    /* Stackoverflow preview fix, please ignore */
    .navbar-nav {
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    .nav-link {
      padding-right: .5rem !important;
      padding-left: .5rem !important;
    }
    
    /* Fixes dropdown menus placed on the right side */
    .ml-auto .dropdown-menu {
      left: auto !important;
      right: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary rounded">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link">Left Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">Left Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">Right Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">            Dropdown on Right</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action with a lot of text inside of an item</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see additional styling rules have been added to account for some oddities in Stackoverflows preview box.
You should be able to safely ignore those rules in your project.

As of v4.0.0 this seems to be the official way to do it.

**EDIT:** I modified the Post to include a dropdown placed on the right side of the navbar as suggested by @Bruno. It needs its `left` and `right` attributes to be inverted. I added an extra snippet of css to the beginning of the example code.
Please note, that the example shows the mobile version when you click the `Run code snippet` button. To view the desktop version you must click the `Expand snippet` button.

```
.ml-auto .dropdown-menu {
    left: auto !important;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Including this in your stylesheet should do the trick.

Comment: Use `ml-auto` for Alpha 6 as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41513463/align-navbar-item-to-the-right-in-bootstrap-4-alpha-6

Comment: Please note that `pull-*-*` has deprecated, use `float-*-*` instead. `float-xs-*` seem not working in alpha6 so use `float-right`

Comment: for alpha 6 check this https://jsbin.com/kemawa/edit?output

Comment: The correct answer is add the class `ml-auto` to the `<ul>`

Comment: I fixed the answer for bootstrap V4 **Beta**.

Comment: This solution `ml-auto` is so non-intuitive on Bootstrap's part, it's sickening. (FYI: This was not a knock to the answer)

Comment: @FastTrack Check out the initial alpha4 answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40193892/1). It is much more intuitive and even had support for different screen sizes.

Comment: Most of the solutions presented here work, but when it's dropdown that is pushed to the right, the dropdown menu is misplaced and its content overflow out of the screen

Comment: @Bruno I updated the answer to include a dropdown example. It requires a little bit of extra css to work correctly.

Comment: They should put what `ml-auto` and `mr-auto` do in the navbar docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: wow bs4 really made it all straighforwrd

Answer (score 283):

In last versions, it is easier. Just put a `ml-auto` class in the `ul` like so:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I was trying mr-auto as suggested above, and it did not work.  Adding ml-auto fixed it for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Worked for me too, thx. Side note: Not sure but with Bootstrap 4 I think that `nav` class isn't needed anymore in `ul`. This would also work: `<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">`

Comment: @kjdion84 Since op seems to be inactive I updated the accepted answer.

Comment: This solution is so non-intuitive on Bootstrap's part, it's sickening. (FYI: This was not a knock to the answer)

Answer (score 40):

This should work for alpha 6. The key is the class "mr-auto" on the left nav, which will push the right nav to the right. You also need to add navbar-toggleable-md or it will stack in a column instead of a row. Note I didn't add the remaining toggle items (e.g. toggle button), I added just enough to get it to formatted as requested. Here are more complete examples https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/navbars/.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link on the Right</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Although your solution works but, we should all agree that whatever solution we use is a workaround, Bootstrap 4 is far from stable and, the rules and naming conventions are constantly changing in way that slows down any development. Thank you for helping us to pass this dilemma until we grab a stable version.


**UPDATE** you should put all classes of `navbar-toggleable-*` so that the navs don't stack up in all screen sizes.

Comment: Not working in JSFiddle using Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 17):

[image: Navbar expanded]

[image: Navbar collapsed]

I have a working codepen with left- and right-aligned nav links that all collapse into a responsive menu together using `.justify-content-between` on the parent tag: https://codepen.io/epan/pen/bREVVW?editors=1000

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar"     aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Acme</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Ball Bearings</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">TNT Boxes</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 14):

In Bootstrap 4 alpha-6 version, As navbar is using flex model, you can use `justify-content-end` in parent's div and remove `mr-auto`.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarText">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This works like a charm :)

Comment: Works for bootstrap 5

Answer (score 1):

With Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6: Two `<ul>`s (`.navbar-na`), one with `.mr-auto` and one with `.ml-auto`:

```
<nav ...> 
  ...     
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left Link </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right Link </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was looking for a solution that allows **one** of the navbar items to be right aligned. In order to do this, you must add `style="width:100%;"` to the `<ul class="navbar-nav">` and *then* add the `ml-auto` class to your navbar item.

Answer (score -1):

Here and easy Example.

```
<!-- Navigation bar-->

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md bg-info navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainMenu">
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto " style="width:100%">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Training</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This doesn't explain anything, the code doesn't easily show what is intended and the worst part if your `style="1width: 100%"` simply wont work, also you should use the class `w-100` not style attributes...