# Bootstrap 4, allign navbar items right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic bootstrap navbar, that collapses. Now i want all of the items in the `<ul>` tag to be on the right side of the screen. When the menu is not collapsed.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-custom">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_navbar" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">&#9776;</span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
        navbar
    </a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The only custom styling at the moment is color in the `navbar-custom` class. This does, as far as i know, not have an effect on the allignment.

I have tried to use `pull-right`, `pull-lg-right`, `float-lg-right`, `justify-????-end` on the `<ul>` tag.

Do anyone have any idea how you could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**

I had to use two list-tags, the first on with the `mr-auto` class. As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178386/bootstrap-4-navbar-items-on-right-side/41769285#41769285)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul> <!-- Add this one -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">home</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using bootstrap, add the class navbar-right to the ul

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

Comment: `navbar-right` does not exist in Bootstrap v4 which is what this question is about, so this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Those pull classes use responsive sizing I believe. Have you tried using something like pull-xs-right?

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-custom pull-xs-right">
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_navbar" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">&#9776;</span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="">
    navbar
</a>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```