# Boostrap how to make navbar <li> elements in same line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make navbar elements appear on same line. I tried overriding .nav class display to inline:block. but it is not working at all. Please help me fix this problem. This is working on bootstrap 3

HTML

```
<head>
  <title>Samrat Luitel website design </title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav">
  <div class="container-fluid topnav">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand topnav" href="#" target="_blank">Samrat Luitel</a>
    </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#home" style="color:black">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home" style="color:black">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home" style="color:black">Home</a></li>
      </ul>   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </nav> 
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
  font-family:"Lato";
  font-weight:700;
}
.navbar-brand{
  color:black;
}
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: i think you should give !important if your are overriding

Comment: can you share jsfiddle code

Comment: You just need horizontal navigation. [Checkout This](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav-pills)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/3.3.7/paper/bootstrap.min.css" />

<head>
  <title>Samrat Luitel website design </title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container topnav">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Samrat Luitel</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks but any link to documentation.  I did not understand this code

Comment: I'm using only bootstrap `css` server side link to execute the `html` as per your requirement you can use your local bootstrap `css` file.

Comment: I'm sorry but your code does not fix the problem. Three "home" are coming vertically. Not horizontally. But they show horizontally If I use boostrap 3. Please try to answer once again. I'm sorry for ill explanation of problem.

Comment: Which bootstrap version you are using ?

Comment: 4. Shall I switch to 3 since I think that is still in beta. Or there is a solution for it

Comment: If you are using bootstrap v4 then you can [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178386/bootstrap-4-navbar-items-on-right-side)

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Pls add inline-block style to your li, so that you can manage your list items.

```
.nav li{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your code does not fix the problem. Three "home" are coming vertically. Not horizontally. But they show horizontally If I use boostrap 3. Please try to answer once again. I'm sorry for ill explanation of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this css `.nav > li {display: inline}`

Comment: I think your html structure have a problem inside `nav` you put `<div class="contianer-fluid">`

Comment: So what shall I do. And is that a problem

Comment: I'm sorry but that does not fix the problem. Three "home" are coming vertically. Not horizontally. But they show horizontally If I use boostrap 3. Please try to answer once again. I'm sorry for ill explanation of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to understand the exact problem but i guess if inline is not working try float

```
.nav > li {float:left:width:30%;}
```

/* New edit */
Try this one

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
     
    
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your code does not fix the problem. Three "home" are coming vertically. Not horizontally. But they show horizontally If I use boostrap 3. Please try to answer once again. I'm sorry for ill explanation of problem.

Comment: try the new one i have used bootstrap v4

Answer (score 0):

Update your css with below css. `Remove display:inline-block;` from `.nav` css rule.

```
.nav {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your code does not fix the problem. Three "home" are coming vertically. Not horizontally. But they show horizontally If I use boostrap 3. Please try to answer once again. I'm sorry for ill explanation of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the suggested solutions with adding something like "... display: inline ..." to my stlyes.css file also did not help me (I also use Bootstrap4).

This is what finally helped me

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-sm">
...
</nav>
```

The important point here is navbar-expand-sm. This says that the nav-bar-items are only stacked vertically when the screen size is smaller or equal to small. 
See further explanation here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Answer (score -2):

```
li {
    float:left;
}
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}
```